# Is there an example of how to use Google Speech to text api in a React Native App

Tags: react-native, google-speech-api

I have been trying to implement this for a while and I have not been able to and I was wondering if there is an example that I could look at.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how are you trying to implement it ?

Comment: What I've heard for React and Xamarin is that the SDK is a wrapper around some C code, and will only work in truly native environments. For example, even with a C# SDK, it won't work in Xamarin.